# wget downloads corrupt JPEG file

Tags: wget

I'm trying to use `wget` to automatically download a wallpaper.  Here is the command:

`wget http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg`

However, if I try to open the resulting picture, it seems to say it has a bad magic number.  By running `file 1600.jpg`, I get `1600.jpg: GIF image data, version 89a, 1 x 1`.  If I open it as a GIF it doesn't work either.  It's only 37 bytes too.

It works perfectly fine if I view or download it through Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's some kind of protection against direct downloads, nothing wrong with `wget` (the server is sending you a transparent 1x1 GIF image).

You can circumvent this by using `wget` with the `-U` flag, adding the user agent string of your browser, eg.:

`wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/11.0.654.0 Chrome/11.0.654.0 Safari/534.17" http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg`

**BUT**: You should first ask the owner of that website if it's ok to download the content this way. There has to be a reason why the usual `wget` approach is blocked (maybe it's intentional, maybe it's just misconfiguration).

Comment: I see.  But why isn't Firefox affected?  And how would I get around that?

Comment: @alecRN: See update.