# wget fails to download an image

Tags: scripts, downloads, wget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [wget downloads corrupt JPEG file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24935/wget-downloads-corrupt-jpeg-file)

I'm trying to do a script so I can set [this image](http://www.die.net/earth/) as background and update it each 10 minutes, but I cannot even download the image:

```
$ wget "http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg" -O imagen.jpg


--2012-08-23 17:51:41--  http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg
Solving static.die.net (static.die.net)... 209.151.236.22, 2607:f820:42::16
Connecting with static.die.net (static.die.net)[209.151.236.22]:80... connected.
HTTP Request sent, waiting reply... 200 OK
Length: 37 [image/gif]
Saving to: “imagen.jpg”

100%[======================================>] 37          --.-K/s   en 0s      

2012-08-23 17:51:42 (5,58 MB/s) - “imagen.jpg” saved [37/37]
```

And `imagen.jpg`'s size is 37 bytes...

Any idea?

NB: Output of `wget` was in Spanish, so I translated into English.

Comment: The answer is probably here http://askubuntu.com/questions/24935/wget-downloads-corrupt-jpeg-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's silently redirecting you to a gif image which just happens to be empty. This is a simple tactic that CDNs use to stop people scraping with tools like `wget`.

Unfortunately (for them) `wget` allows you to spoof another user agent string like so:

```
wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1' http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg
```

But you should probably interpret their empty image response as a "please don't use wget on our servers". It's probably in their terms of service.

Comment: Good to know, it seems useful.

Answer (score 3):

This image comes as a feature to the Wallch program as well. As mentioned here: http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php Wallch uses a third-party image hoster so as to provide this image, for protection of static.die.net's bandwidth.

So, if you want this image as your background you can go and download Wallch (it is at the Ubuntu Software Center).

By the way, the image is updated every 30 minutes, not every 10.